# Date Formatter Issue when parsing date of type "2020-03-30T07:37:02.282+01:00" i have to format in the form today at 12:30 am

Tags: simpledateformat, datetimeoffset, dateformatter

I am facing issue while formatting the date and time of the type "2020-03-30T07:37:02.282+01:00"
and i am getting date from my server in these two formats "2020-03-30T07:37:02.282+01:00" and 
“2020-03-30T05:44:02.397Z” I think i am using the correct time but not sure while parsing i am getting parsable expection for the date type "2020-03-30T07:37:02.282+01:00" but i am able to parse the date of type “2020-03-30T05:44:02.397Z”.Code i am using for formatting the date is

```
    fun formatToYesterdayOrToday(responseTime: String?): String? {
    val dateTime: Date =
        SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
            Locale.getDefault()
        ).parse(responseTime)
    val calendar: Calendar =
        Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = dateTime
    val today: Calendar =
        Calendar.getInstance()
    val yesterday: Calendar =
        Calendar.getInstance()
    yesterday.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
    val timeFormatter: DateFormat =
        SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma", Locale.getDefault())
    val dateFormatter: DateFormat =
        SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    return if (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == today.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    ) {
        "Updated: " + setAmPmToLowercase(timeFormatter.format(dateTime)) + " today"
    } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == yesterday.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == yesterday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == yesterday.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    ) {
        "Updated: " + setAmPmToLowercase(timeFormatter.format(dateTime) + " yesterday")
    } else {
        "Updated on: " + dateFormatter.format(dateTime) + " at " + setAmPmToLowercase(
            timeFormatter.format(dateTime)
        )
    }
}
```

Can any one please help me with what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. All of those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You may also want to tag your question with the language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Those two strings — `2020-03-30T07:37:02.282+01:00` and `2020-03-30T05:44:02.397Z` — have the same format. The format is ISO 8601 (see the link at the bottom). In ISO 8601, an offset from UTC (or GMT) may be given as either `Z` for zero or for example `+01:00` for 1 hour 0 minutes (more variants exist).

You should prefer to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Also `java.time.OffsetDateTime` parses ISO 8601 as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter. So we don’t need to bother thinking about a format pattern string. In Java:

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime
            = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-03-30T07:37:02.282+01:00");
    System.out.println(dateTime);
    dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-03-30T05:44:02.397Z");
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> ```
> 2020-03-30T07:37:02.282+01:00
> 2020-03-30T05:44:02.397Z
> ```

You notice that `OffsetDateTime.toString()` (implicitly called when we print the object) is returning ISO 8601 format too.

Even if we had needed to write a format pattern string for a formatter, you should *never* hardcode `Z` as a literal (by putting it in single quotes). As I said, `Z` is an offset from UTC and needs to be parsed as such, or either you will not be able to parse the string or — worse — you risk getting incorrect results from doing it. In all likelihood you were getting an incorrect result when you said you were able to parse `2020-03-30T05:44:02.397Z`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)